# Abstract derivatives in Feyncalc

Tags: physics, feyncalc

I have encountered several problems regarding the application of formal derivative operators in FeynCalc, using the built-in function FCPartialD,
Left/RightPartialD

**Schematic description of my original problem**

My starting point is a lagrangian $L(U)$ for a matrix-valued field $U(x)$, which generically involves products, derivatives, traces, etc. I can also express $U(x)$ as the exponential $U = e^{\sum_i \phi_i(x) T_i}$, where the $\phi_i(x)$'s are scalar fields and the $T_i's$ constant matrices. I would like to expand $L$ at fixed order in the number of $\phi$ fields. However, I cannot implement field derivatives properly.

**Specific issues**

1) I can act on fields with LeftPartialD, and apply the Leibniz rule with ExpandD. However, the resulting expression is not simplified, somehow assuming the fields are not commuting.

Input:

`DotSimplify[ExpandPartialD[QuantumField[A].QuantumField[A].LeftPartialD[\[Nu]]]]`

Output:

$A.\left(\left.(\partial _{\nu }A\right)\right)+\left(\left.(\partial _{\nu }A\right)\right).A$

2) If I try the same command on the matrix Sigma[1](https://feyncalc.github.io/reference) (first order expansion of the $U$ above), the derivative is not actually applied to the individual matrix components, but only to the matrix as a whole.

Input:

`ExpandPartialD[Sigma1.LeftPartialD[\[Nu]]]`

Output: (MatrixForm of Sigma1). $\partial^{\leftarrow}_{\nu}$

As a corollary, the Leibniz rule isn't applied.

3) If I try to use FCPartialD instead, the Leibniz rule is not applied, not even on a single field.

Input:

`ExpandPartialD[FCPartialD[\[Nu]].(QuantumField[A].QuantumField[A])]`

Output:

$\partial _{\nu }.A.A$

I would be grateful for any solutions to the problems above/alternative suggestions on how to perform the task. For reference, I include the links to the Feyncalc reference guide, containing entries for the specific functions I mentioned.

[Guide](https://feyncalc.github.io/reference)

Comment: Hello dude, my suggestion is to ask on the FeynCalc forums here: https://feyncalc.github.io/forum.  You might more readily get feedback on your question there.

Comment: Thanks, just done!